# Draw ring-like shape in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Is this shape drawable with `.AddShape`?
Which is his `MsoAutoShapeType` and how can I set the size of the internal circle?

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I lost it in translation, I'm not english and we usually call it ring, as well as the chart of the same shape, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To adjust the **internal** circle you need to generate the donut first,

```
.AddShape(MsoAutoShapeType, Left, Top, Width, Height)
```

where `Width` and `Height` define the outer circle. And then adjust the inner circle of the shape with

```
.DrawingObject.ShapeRange.Adjustments.Item(1) = 0.45
```

So we have something like this

```
Dim myShape As Shape
Set myShape = Worksheets("MySheetName").Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeDonut, 10, 10, 50, 50)
myShape.DrawingObject.ShapeRange.Adjustments.Item(1) = 0.45
```

and it looks like that:

[image]

---

For references see:

- [Shapes.AddShape Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/shapes-addshape-method-excel)
- [MsoAutoShapeType Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa432469(v=office.12).aspx)